# Xcode search bar not running function

Tags: iphone, search, uisearchbar

I am going crazy with this search bar in storyboards and have been trough loads of tutorials.

I have a search bar on my view and set it as an outlet

```
IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

how do I run code when the user clicks 'DONE' on the keyboard. I have tried this but nothing works

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven' used the storyboards for XCode, but have you made sure to set the viewController as the searchBar's delegate?

Comment: oh right, tiredness error i put "searchBar.delegate = self;" and now it works :D

Comment: it works but the code I posted in last comment cause the warning:

    Passing 'Home *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UISearchBarDelegate>'

Comment: Have you made sure to add `UISearchBarDelegate` to the header of whatever `self` is (I am assuming `Home`)? So at the top (also assuming `Home` is a standard subclass of `UIViewController`) it reads:

`@interface Home : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>`

Answer (score 0):

searchBarSearchButtonClicked should work, but have you tried searchBarResultsListButtonClicked and searchBarTextDidEndEditing. Btw, is this iphone or ipad? and check your delegate is set correctly.